# Getting value from (select2) to another filed input laravel

Tags: laravel

I have select2 field input. After using select2 its will showing new column and data from this input selected.

I have referenced like this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange). So after I using select2, this value will show in a new column. But I don't know how to catch this data. I am using Laravel and this is my controller and view:

Controller

```
 $collection = Alat::get(['nama_alat','no_inventaris','status_alat','id']);
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $inven[$item->id]  = $item->no_inventaris.'-'.$item->nama_alat;
    }
```

This is will shown in columns `no_inventaris` and `nama_alat` in the select2. But in the `$collection`, I have `status_alat`, this data is what I need to display in another column.

This is my view:

```
            // This is form Select2
               <div class="form-group"> 
                      <label>Pilih Inventaris</label>
                      <select class="form-control select2bs4" name="alat_id" id="alat_id" style="width: 100%;" aria-hidden="true" onchange="Show()">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        @foreach($inven as $id => $item )
                        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $item }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                        
                      </select>
                    </div>

                   // This is form what i need to show another value
                  <div class="form-group" id="divid" style="display:none">
                        <label class="control-label" for="title">Kondisi Alat Sekarang:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="value" data-error="Please enter title." readonly />
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                      </div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
 <script>
  function Show()
   {
      var fieldValue =  $('#alat_id').val();
 
 
         if(fieldValue == "")
          {
           document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'none';
            }
         else{
           document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'inline'
           }           
      }
 
 </script>
```

This data I need to catch in the controller `$collection` as `status_alat`. How can I catch this data after input the select2 and showing in the new column? This column is shown, but I don't know how to catch this data. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

The best solution should be using ajax, it is quite complicated to access a PHP collection variable inside a javascript. If it were me, I would create a function that fetch the selected select2 data by its id. This is my example code :

```
<script>
  function select2Changed()
   {
      var alat_id =  $('#alat_id').val();  
      if(fieldValue == ""){
           document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'none';
      } else{
           document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'inline';
           $.ajax({url: "[url]/get-alat-status/"+alat_id, success: function(result){
               document.getElementById("value").value = result;
           }}); 
      }       
   }

 </script>
```

Comment: so i what i need to add more this controller ?

Comment: <script>
  function Show()
   {
      var fieldValue =  $('#alat_id').val();
 
 
         if(fieldValue == "")
          {
           document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'none';
            }
         else{
           document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'inline';
           var alat_id =  $('#alat_id').val();     
            $.ajax({url: "[url]/get-alat-status/"+alat_id, success: function(result){
            document.getElementById("value").value = result; // because your input id is value
      }});     
           }           
    }
 </script>

Comment: 1. you should add a function in your controller, it should return a status of the alat
2. Then if you want to use your function, it would looks like this the answer (I edited it)
```

Comment: i need create a function return status_alat and id , like i create a dropdown ?

Comment: Yes, it is in your laravel controller, it should return a `json` or `string` instead of a normal `return $this->view()`

Comment: wait sir , can see my controller in my question ? i cant used this ?

Comment: you can use the controller above, but for my solution to work, you should add a function in your controller for the ajax request